# Windows Phone 8 jQuery.ajax on local file fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

Although, having read a lot of discussion about this question, I could not find a working answer.

I am developing a phonegap application which should run on both Windows Phone and iOS. For internationalization I use jQuery globalize (https://github.com/jquery/globalize) which works fine in a desktop browser (IE, Firefox) and in Safari. However, I need to access some JSON files for initializing the globalization engine which is the issue when working with Windows Phone, as I can not locate the required files. The files are located in the directory `res/lang/cldr/` which has two subdirectories containing language-specific files. Here is my code for loading the demanded files:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", {
        cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json", error: function (exceptionType, exceptionStatus, httpStatus) {
            // TODO: remove in production version
            console.log(httpStatus);
        }
    }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/timeData.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/weekData.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/en/numbers.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/en/timeZoneNames.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/en/caGregorian.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/de/numbers.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/de/timeZoneNames.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" }),
    $.ajax("res/lang/cldr/de/caGregorian.json", { cache: false, isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json" })
).then(function () {
    // Normalize $.ajax results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
    return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
        return result[0];
    });
}).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
    // load the messages displayed by the application
    $.ajax("res/lang/messages.json", {
        isLocal: true, async: false, dataType: "json", success: function (messages, status, request) {
            Globalize.loadMessages(messages);
        }, error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried the following workarounds, but non of these works:

```
$.ajax("www/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("/www/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("./res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("./www/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("x-wmapp0://www/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("x-wmapp0:/www/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ... (jsconsole.com used this as name of the file causing the exception
$.ajax("x-wmapp0://res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
$.ajax("x-wmapp0:/res/lang/cldr/likelySubtags.json", ...
```

However, loading a file directly out of the root directory works fine:

```
// works
$.ajax({ url: fragmentURL, dataType: "html", cache: true, isLocal: true, processData: true, success: function(switchableFragment) { ... } }); // It works!!!
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova for Windows Phone (I confirmed it on vesions 3.5 or lower) has several problems on loading JSON files. To resolve it, you should work on **XHRHelper.cs** cordova file or try a easier way. Let's see both solutions:

**1 -** You can try the following code on **XHRHelper.cs** inside **HandleCommand** method:

```
Uri relUri = new Uri(uri.AbsolutePath, UriKind.Relative);

if (uri.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("json"))
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(uri.AbsolutePath))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        InvokeCallback(url, 200, json);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**2 -** The easiest way. You can try change your JSON files extension to TXT and than parse the result string as a JSON object with Javascript. See:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'res/lang/cldr/JSONFile.txt',
    success: function (data) {
        var content = JSON.parse(data);

        doWhateverYouWant(content);
    }
});
```

Bot solutions worked for me when I had the same problem. Hope it helps!

Best regards!